# Java WS cast error

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm getting an error and not sure why,

this is my project setup:

[image]

Whenever I run a server method that references Book.java, I get this error message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.client.Book cannot be cast to com.server.Book
```

Can i not have the same class on both the client and server?

This is the code for my `Book` class

*The only difference is in the package declaration

```
package com.client; /* on client side*/
package com.server; /* on server side */

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Book implements Serializable
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name, author;
private int copiesAvail;
private int daysToReturn;
public Book()
{

}

public Book (String name, String author)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    copiesAvail = 1;
    daysToReturn = 0;
}

// getters
public String getName() {return name;}
public String getAuthor() {return author;}
public int getCopiesAvail() {return copiesAvail;}
public int getDaysToReturn() {return daysToReturn;}

// setters
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
public void setAuthor(String author) {this.author= author;}
public void setCopiesAvail(int copiesAvail) {this.copiesAvail = copiesAvail;}
public void setDaysToReturn(int daysToReturn) {this.daysToReturn = daysToReturn;}

public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + getName()
            + "\nAuthor: " + getAuthor()
            + "\nNumber of Copies Available: " + getCopiesAvail();
}

}
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two classes, although they shares the same name, are two totally different, incompatible classes. The Book in client package and server package does not have a Is-A relationship so the cast will surely fail.

You don't have to have two classes with the exactly the same implementation. If this class is used both by the client and the server, the standard way is to put this class in another package, say "common" and shares between the client and server code.

Answer (score 1):

you can have both (Book.java on client package and on server package). But why did you do that?  They do the same work, so no need to have two classes.

Remove one class and use the other one on both sides. That would also resolve your issue. And move the class into a neutral package because it is used on both sides server an client.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did that, put `Book.java` in `/com` and changed the `import` references in both client and server. Now I'm getting `ClassNotFoundException: com.client.Book` It seem's it is still looking for it in `/com/client`

Comment: Did you build the projects again? Clean all projects and compile and build everythong once again.